# Basic jQuery javascript countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, countdown

I KNOW that this is basic. But I'm so JS-retarded I can't "do-it-myself" and I'm tired of spending hours getting nowhere. Please help!

There are dozens of JS countdowns I find by Googling & on jQuery.org. The one I'm trying to modify is http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tgcCountdown because it's the kind of BASIC counter I need. But it only offers the countdown based on a given SQL timestamp, and I need a 2nd option of a fixed timer, e.g. 5 minutes from NOW.

Any advice? I know it's gotta be simple! `secs = 300` or `now.getTime() + 300` or something like that! I'm so close but I just can't get there!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064186/how-can-i-make-a-jquery-countdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Using http://phrogz.net/JS/FormatDateTime_JS.txt
var fiveMinutesFromNow = new Date( (new Date)*1 + 1000 * 60 * 5 );
var timestamp = fiveMinutesFromNow.customFormat( '#YYYY##MM##DD##hhh##mm##ss#' );
console.log( timestamp );
// "20110207122917"
```

**Edit** to work for Firefox

Comment: Try that in the console: "Invalid Date"

Comment: Firefox/firebug.  `new Date( new Date + 5 )` gets me five minutes from now

Comment: @bdukes How odd of FF to do that; fixed; note that `+ 5` will only get you 5ms in the future on Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for this, very very helpful - especially the TXT file you reference in the commented portion of your script! I'm struggling to stop the countdown prematurely. Is there an easy way to do this? For example: `$('#stop').click(function() {countdownStop()});`