# Popup Div Over Entire Website? (On first pageload)

Tags: jquery, css, html, cookies

Instead of creating an intro page, I'm trying to display a div over the entire website that will have a background image, some text, and a countdown, and an exit button. Is there a way to display this div only a certain amount of times for an IP address? That way it loads once The div would look something like this.

```
<div id="divbgimg">
<span id="titletext">text text text</span>
<span id="subtitletext">text text text</span>
<span id="date">10/11/12</span>
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Is there any jQuery script I should look at to do something like this?

Comment: One of my favorite pet peeves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Reveal - http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly something like the JQuery Modal Dialog could be what you're after. Take a look here

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` or delay `function` function. You can hide you div after certain time

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#divbgimg').fadeOut();
}, 1000)//100ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to display the div and then set a cookie to state that you have visited the page...

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Then when you next visit the page, check if the cookie exists and (if it does), don't show the div overlay.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it like this:

HTML:

```
<div id='lb_background'></div>
<div id='lb_front'>This is where your content will go!<div id="countdown"></div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#lb_background {
position: absolute; /*THIS IS REQUIRED!*/
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
z-index: 1000; /* In front of everything */
opacity: 0.6;
}
#lb_front {
padding: 20px;
z-index: 1001; /* In front of lb_background */
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('#lb_background').click(function(){
   $('#lb_background, #lb_front').fadeOut(200)
});
```

**EDIT**
The above is just what I use for creating the lightbox easily. As for the countdown and timer that is slightly different.

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
  var count = 10;
  countdown = setInterval(function(){
    $("#countdown").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
    if (count == 0) {
      $('#lb_background, $lb_front').fadeOut(200);
    }
    count--;
  }, 1000);
});
```

(From: [How can I make a jQuery countdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064186/how-can-i-make-a-jquery-countdown) )