# JQuery Countdown timer with Configurable start time

Tags: jquery, timer, countdown, configure

I would like to have a timer that would allow a user (of my website) to input how much time they want the countdown to go for (on a scale of minutes and seconds), as well as have a start/stop function.

I've searched for something like this, but I only can seem to find countdown timers that countdown to a specific date, or date pickers that don't seem to have any timer functionality.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you looking for a ready-to-use component? You can consider writing it by yourself. I suppose this can be done with javascript and jQuery. To get started, take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064186/how-can-i-make-a-jquery-countdown. If you need help with the code, let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an interesting plugin.

http://jchavannes.com/jquery-timer/demo

look at the 2nd example.

source http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/