# Auto Refresh Div Using jQuery from 5 Seconds to Zero

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How to create a countdown counter in Drupal 7 that says:

```
Your download will start in 5 seconds...
```

During page load and it countdown the number to 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

And change the value to

```
Your download will start shortly...
```

When finished?

I found so many tutorials about this but not specific to what I am looking for.

I am also moving this question from [Drupal stackexchange](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80641/auto-refresh-div-using-jquery-from-5-seconds-to-zero?noredirect=1#comment90813_80641) as suggested by Chapabu.

Comment: Never mind this question as it is already answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

25 jQuery countdown scripts here: http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/04/jquery-countdown-scripts.html and the according StackOverflow-Question including excellent answers: [How can I make a jQuery countdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064186/how-can-i-make-a-jquery-countdown)