# Traffic light jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote jQuery plugin, that simulates work of traffic light. You can see demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eko24ive/FeqFd/4/), and the source code:

```
$.fn.plugin = function (b/*time*/,a/*starting with given color*/) {
    b.push(b[1]);//adding phases time to plugin array 
    return this.each(function (f, d) {
        var
            e = ["#008000", "#FFFF00", "#FF0000", "#FFFF00"],//green,yellow,red,yellow
            c = function () {
                $(d).html(b[a])// here i want to place time, that left for current phase, it should change dynamicly
                    .css({
                        "background-color": e[a]//changing bg as light
                    });
             window.setTimeout(c, 1000 * b[a]);//hold phase as long as we told to plugin
             a = ++a % 4//result would be 0..1..2..3 and so on
            };
        c()
    })
};

$(window).load(function(){
$("#c1").plugin([2,2,2],0);
$("#c2").plugin([2,2,2],2);
})

</head>
<body>
Starts with red:<span id="c1" style="">&nbsp;</span><br>
Starts with green:<span id="c2" style="">&nbsp;</span><br>
```

So, as you can see i'm selecting element, add plugin, writing time of phases for green,yellow,red, and with what color traffic light should begin.

```
$(d).html(b[a])
```

This part of code just writing time for current phase.
I want to this number showed the time left for the phase.

Comment: I [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2064217/54680) a question similar to this a while back.