# CountDown jQuery whith data inside <body> tag

Tags: jquery, countdown, document-body

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064186/how-can-i-make-a-jquery-countdown) post I have this scenario

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
    // Our countdown plugin takes a callback, a duration, and an optional message
    $.fn.countdown = function (callback, duration, message) {
    // If no message is provided, we use an empty string
    message = message || "";
    // Get reference to container, and set initial content
    var container = $(this[0]).html(duration + message);
    // Get reference to the interval doing the countdown
    var countdown = setInterval(function () {
        // If seconds remain
        if (--duration) {
            // Update our container's message
            container.html(duration + message);
        // Otherwise
        } else {
            // Clear the countdown interval
            clearInterval(countdown);
            // And fire the callback passing our container as `this`
            callback.call(container);   
        }
    // Run interval every 1000ms (1 second)
    }, 1000);

    };
    // Function to be called after 5 seconds
     function redirect () {
     this.html("<a href='mypdf.pdf'>Donwload</a>");
     window.location = "http://msdn.microsoft.com";
     }
  </script>
 
 </head>
  <body>
```

Now, after `"<boby>"` tag I have an classic Asp response.write/flush like this:

```
<%
  ToLoop = 29
  for i = 0 to ToLoop
      StartTimer = Timer 'define time in second from 12:00AM

       if i = 1 then
         Count_Start_Second = round(This_Loop_Timer * ToLoop) 'use round for integer a decimal number
           response.write "<div id='countdown'></div>"
           response.write"<script>" & _
            "$('#countdown').countdown(redirect, " & Count_Start_Second & ", ""s remaining"");" & _
             "</script>"
           response.flush 
       end if

         --------More and more asp code to compile a dinamic PDF----------

        EndTimer = Timer 'define time in second after loop
        This_Loop_Timer = EndTimer - StartTimer 
  next
%>
```

I don't understand why the jQuery is executed after the page has finished loading? With the Flush, theorically, should load immediately after the first lap of the loop. But isn't.

Comment: I don't believe so. Since the connection hasn't closed yet, your DOM isn't loaded and Javascript won't run yet. You are referring to the $ jquery variable and it hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot to insert a code in my post. This: response.write "<div id='countdown'></div>"

Comment: Since you are using a flush command and a timer in ASP, your page never finished loading, therefore none of your Jquery countdown code is running. That is why it runs after the page is finished, not during like your expecting. Also I'm assuming your even referencing the JQuery library ( I didn't see a script reference to it )

Comment: yes there's a JQ library. The CountDown starts after, not during, but starts. But if I use another $ function like $('#someID').html('newText'), it works with flush and during loop (in other words, in real-time)

Comment: could you just flush <script>redirect();</script>?

Comment: Re `<boby>` tag, do you mean `<body>`?